# need to show the next day (script shows current day)

Tags: php, html

```
<body>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Fiji');
$day = date('l', mktime());
$day = strtolower($day).".html";

/*
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$trace = explode("/", $path);
$count = count ($trace) - 1;
$trace[$count] = $day;
$path = implode("/", $trace);
echo $path;
*/

if (file_exists($day)) 
{
    include($day); 
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Like `$day = date('l', strtotime('+1 day'));` ?

Comment: tried that does not work

Comment: Define doesn't work. Error or just doesn't include. If it's not including then the file isn't where you're telling it.

Comment: yes it does not include but with the existing code it works for the current day

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get next day is to use strtotime:

```
echo date('l', strtotime(date("Y-m-d") .' +1 day'));
```

You can skip date("Y-m-d"), i put in there to show you, that you can get +1 day from any date you want

Comment: Thanks daimos have managed to get it to work using the following  $day = date('l', strtotime(date($day) .' +1 day'));

Answer (score 0):

Did you try anything?

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-10-27 12:00:00'); // pick a date (today)

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // show it

$date->modify('+1 day'); // add + 1 day

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // shows tomorrow
```

Comment: Hi slick , the script focuses on day and does not need time and date, so it is cycling through Monday to Sunday

Comment: You are more lazy than I thought. Change date format to show the number that represents number of day instead of full date and you're done.

Comment: i have no experience at coding or web design ,my company has just dumped this on me as the other staff looking after this left. I am trying to put the pieces together thus my need for assistance

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Fiji');
$day = date('l', strtotime('+1 day'));
/*
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$trace = explode("/", $path);
$count = count ($trace) - 1;
$trace[$count] = $day;
$path = implode("/", $trace);
echo $path;
*/

if (file_exists($day)) 
{
    include($day); 
}
?>
</body>
```

Updated changes for your code to show next day of the week.

Comment: lone ranger , tried that doesn't work and now also does not show post

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>    
<?php    
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Fiji');    
$day = date('l', strtotime(date($day) .' +1 day'));    
$day = strtolower($day).".html";
/*    
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];    
$trace = explode("/", $path);    
$count = count ($trace) - 1;    
$trace[$count] = $day;    
$path = implode("/", $trace);    
echo $path;    
*/

if (file_exists($day))     
{    
    include($day);     
}    
?></body>
```